# spring mvc and hibernate should save the transaction on demand

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, autocommit

I am using spring mvc and hibernate. the following is sample of my code.

**applicationContext.xml**

```
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.soft.erp" />
<mvc:annotation-driven /> 
<import resource="hibernate-context.xml" />
```

**config.properties**

```
app.jdbc.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
app.jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/besoin
app.jdbc.username=root
app.jdbc.password=7886
hibernate.config=/WEB-INF/hibernate.cfg.xml
```

**hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
<property name="show_sql">false</property>
```

**hibernate-context.xml**

```
    <context:property-placeholder location="/WEB-INF/config.properties" />
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />   
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean"
             p:dataSource-ref="dataSource"
             p:configLocation="${hibernate.config}"
             p:packagesToScan="com.soft.erp"/>
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
            destroy-method="close"
            p:driverClass="${app.jdbc.driverClassName}"
            p:jdbcUrl="${app.jdbc.url}"
            p:user="${app.jdbc.username}"
            p:password="${app.jdbc.password}"

            p:acquireIncrement="5"
            p:idleConnectionTestPeriod="60"
            p:maxPoolSize="100"
            p:maxStatements="50"
            p:minPoolSize="10" />
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager" 
            p:sessionFactory-ref="sessionFactory" />
```

**COACategoriesModel.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "COACATEGORIES")
public class COACategoriesModel {

@Id
@Column(name = "COACATEGORIESID")
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;


public COACategoriesModel() {
    super();
}

@Column(name = "COACATEGORIESNAME")
private String name;

@Column(name = "RECENTUSERID")
private long recentUserId;

@Column(name = "RECENTUSERIP")
private String recentUserIp;

@Column(name = "DATE")
private Date dateTime;

@Column(name = "ISUPDATED")
private int isUpdated;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="categoryId")
private List<COAMaintenanceModel> obj = null;


public COACategoriesModel( String name, long recentUserId,
        String recentUserIp, Date dateTime, int isUpdated) {

    this.name = name;
    this.recentUserId = recentUserId;
    this.recentUserIp = recentUserIp;
    this.dateTime = dateTime;
    this.isUpdated = isUpdated;
}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public Long getRecentUserId() {
    return recentUserId;
}

public void setRecentUserId(Long recentUserId) {
    this.recentUserId = recentUserId;
}

public String getRecentUserIp() {
    return recentUserIp;
}

public void setRecentUserIp(String recentUserIp) {
    this.recentUserIp = recentUserIp;
}

public Date getDateTime() {
    return dateTime;
}

public void setDateTime(Date dateTime) {
    this.dateTime = dateTime;
}

public int getIsUpdated() {
    return isUpdated;
}

public void setIsUpdated(int isUpdated) {
    this.isUpdated = isUpdated;
}

public void setRecentUserId(long recentUserId) {
    this.recentUserId = recentUserId;
}

public List<COAMaintenanceModel> getObj() {
    return obj;
}

public void setObj(List<COAMaintenanceModel> obj) {
    this.obj = obj;
}
```

**COAMaintenanceModel.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ACCOUNTMAINTENANCE")
public class COAMaintenanceModel {

@Id
@Column(name = "ID")
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;

@Column(name = "ACCOUNT")
private String account;

@Column(name = "DESCRIPTION")
private String discription;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="COACATEGORIESID")
private COACategoriesModel categoryId;

@Column(name = "POSTINGTYPE")
private int postingType;

@Column(name = "TYPICALBALANCE")
private int typicalBalance;

@Column(name = "DEBITBALANCE")
private double debitBalance;

@Column(name = "CREDITBALANCE")
private double creditBalance;

@Column(name = "NETBALANCE")
private double runningBalance;

@Column(name = "DEFAULTCURRENCYID")
private double defaultCurrencyId;

@Column(name = "ISACTIVE")
private int isActive;

@Column(name = "RECENTUSERID")
private Long recentUserId;

@Column(name = "RECENTUSERIP")
private String recentUserIp;

@Column(name = "DATETIME")
private Date dateTime;

@Column(name = "ISUPDATED")
private int isUpdated;

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getAccount() {
    return account;
}

public void setAccount(String account) {
    this.account = account;
}

public String getDiscription() {
    return discription;
}

public void setDiscription(String discription) {
    this.discription = discription;
}

public COACategoriesModel getCategoryId() {
    return categoryId;
}

public void setCategoryId(COACategoriesModel categoryId) {
    this.categoryId = categoryId;
}

public int getPostingType() {
    return postingType;
}

public void setPostingType(int postingType) {
    this.postingType = postingType;
}

public int getTypicalBalance() {
    return typicalBalance;
}

public void setTypicalBalance(int typicalBalance) {
    this.typicalBalance = typicalBalance;
}

public double getDebitBalance() {
    return debitBalance;
}

public void setDebitBalance(double debitBalance) {
    this.debitBalance = debitBalance;
}

public double getCreditBalance() {
    return creditBalance;
}

public void setCreditBalance(double creditBalance) {
    this.creditBalance = creditBalance;
}

public double getRunningBalance() {
    return runningBalance;
}

public void setRunningBalance(double runningBalance) {
    this.runningBalance = runningBalance;
}

public double getDefaultCurrencyId() {
    return defaultCurrencyId;
}

public void setDefaultCurrencyId(double defaultCurrencyId) {
    this.defaultCurrencyId = defaultCurrencyId;
}

public int getIsActive() {
    return isActive;
}

public void setIsActive(int isActive) {
    this.isActive = isActive;
}

public Long getRecentUserId() {
    return recentUserId;
}

public void setRecentUserId(Long recentUserId) {
    this.recentUserId = recentUserId;
}

public String getRecentUserIp() {
    return recentUserIp;
}

public void setRecentUserIp(String recentUserIp) {
    this.recentUserIp = recentUserIp;
}

public Date getDateTime() {
    return dateTime;
}

public void setDateTime(Date dateTime) {
    this.dateTime = dateTime;
}

public int getIsUpdated() {
    return isUpdated;
}

public void setIsUpdated(int isUpdated) {
    this.isUpdated = isUpdated;
}
```

**COACategoriesService.java**

```
@Service("COACategoriesService")
@Transactional 
public class COACategoriesService {


@Resource(name="sessionFactory")
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;


public void AddCOACategories(COACategoriesModel accountCategories) {

Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
session.save(accountCategories);

}
```

}

**COAMaintenanceService.java**

```
@Service("COAMaintenanceService")
@Transactional
public class COAMaintenanceService {


@Resource(name="sessionFactory")
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;



public void AddCOAMaintenance(COAMaintenanceModel cMaintenanceModel) {

Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
session.save(cMaintenanceModel);

}
```

}

**COACategoriesController.java**

```
@Controller
public class COACategoriesController {

protected static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(COACategoriesController.class);


@Resource(name="COACategoriesService")
private COACategoriesService obj_coacs;
@Resource(name="COAMaintenanceService")
private COAMaintenanceService obj_coams;

 @RequestMapping(value = "/addCoaCategory", method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public String addCoaCategory(@RequestParam("conCatName") String coaCatName, Model model) {

     Date sysdate = null;
     String Message="";
     try{

     sysdate = new Date();

     COACategoriesModel model1 = new COACategoriesModel( coaCatName, 1, "", sysdate , 0);

     COAMaintenanceModel account =  new COAMaintenanceModel();
        account.setDiscription("Test Description");
        account.setCategoryId(model1);

        Message="Fail-First";
        obj_coacs.AddCOACategories(model1);


        Message="Fail-Second";
        obj_coams.AddCOAMaintenance (account);


        Message="Successfully Added!";
     }catch(Exception ex){
         log.error("Exception.."+ex);
         model.addAttribute("message", Message);
     }


        return "fin/category";
    }



 }
```

There is a one to many relation between COACategoriesModel to COAMaintenanceModel. AS obj_coacs.AddCOACategories(model1) add the transaction in the table and if there an exception occur in obj_coams.AddCOAMaintenance (account), it not rollback all the transaction.

How to control this. when all the objects successfully insert the transaction into tables, then commit the complete transaction.

What is tha easiest way, with the current scenerio

Answer (score 0):

Specify a value for the `cascade` element on the `@OneToMany` annotation.  This will cause the `COAMaintenanceModel` to be persisted when the `CAOCategoriesModel` is saved.  By default transactions should commit and rollback appropriately depending on whether an exception is thrown.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "COACATEGORIES")
public class COACategoriesModel {

    /* Code ommitted */

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="categoryId", cascade=CascadeType.All)
    private List<COAMaintenanceModel> obj = null;

    /* Code ommitted */
}
```

Comment: not working. Actually I required to commit transaction at the end manually